# Redirect http request(via browser) to local server

Tags: node.js, http, browser, port

I have nodejs http server running on port 9000.
Now for some hostname how do i redirect normal request to this port.

Example : if I hit www.specficDomain.com in browser, it should go to www.specficDomain.com:9000.

Thanks,
Shantanu

Comment: It depends. What's serving requests on port 80? Is that also node or something else?

Comment: its not node..Node is serving on 9000. 80 is the default one. Is it possible for node to server on 80

Comment: Node can serve on any port, but how to redirect to port 9000 depends on what software (e.g. Apache, nginx, haproxy, etc.) is already serving traffic on port 80.